# Why does the following code only prints out the memory locations in python 2.7?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Following code is written to find the E-mail addresses of a given string. But when I print out it gives only the memory locations. So how do I get the values in following code? I'm using Python 2.7. I think following code is written in Python3.

```
import re

    emails = '''
    CoreyMSchafer@gmail.com
    corey.schafer@university.edu
    corey-321-schafer@my-work.net
    '''

    pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+')

    matches = pattern.finditer(emails)

    for match in matches:
        print match
```

Source: https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/Python-Regular-Expressions/simple.py

Comment: you mean to print `match.group(0)` maybe not the match object

Answer (score 1):

you're printing the *representation* of the match object itself, more useful for debugging. In python 2, no great effort has been made on that representation, it just prints the object type and the address:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000003425E68>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000003425ED0>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000003425E68>
```

On my python 3 version I get a better printout, probably it's time to migrate to python 3...:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 24), match='CoreyMSchafer@gmail.com'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(25, 53), match='corey.schafer@university.edu'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(54, 83), match='corey-321-schafer@my-work.net'>
```

Anyway, you want to print the main captured group:

```
for match in matches:
    print(match.group(0))
```

result:

```
CoreyMSchafer@gmail.com
corey.schafer@university.edu
corey-321-schafer@my-work.net
```

note that you should normally test `if match is not None:` before accessing to `group` (in case of a `re.match` which doesn't match) but here since the result has been created by `finditer`, it's guaranteed that you get match objects, not `None`